# Mongoose not recognizing .all() promise function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose, promise

I am trying to use promises to work with the async queries of mongoose against a mongodb database.

I need to validate against a single item, and then against an array of items if they exist in the mongodb.

I have tried callbacks, async/await, and now Im attempting promises. But I cant seem to get the thing to work.

I need to make sure one thing happens only after the other has completed. I also have to construct a list of items that do and do not exist within the database and pass that along to the next promise.

However it seems that .all() is not accepted by mongoose as I am getting the following Error:

```
TypeError: validateInputClass(...).then(...).all is not a function
```

The path Im currently working with is:

```
app.route('/users/enroll/:classId').put(todoList.enroll_in_class);
```

The body I pass is:
    `{ "users":["lorem","ipsum"] }`

And here is my implementation of the code Im working with that is giving me an error saying that .all() is not a function

```
function validateInputClass(inputclassId){
  return Class.findOne({ classId: inputclassId}, function(err, classs) {
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
  });
}

exports.enroll_in_class = function(req, res){
  var userLogArray = req.body.users.map(function(user){
          new Promise((user) => {console.log(user)});
        })
  if(req.body.users.length > 0){
    validateInputClass(req.params.classId)
      .then((response) => {
        if(response){
          return response;
       } else {
          res.json({"message":"Class does not exist"})
       }
      }).all((userLogArray => {
            console.log("Done");
      });
  }
}
```

Ive been beating my head against the wall for the last few hours. I cant seem to figure this out

Comment: Promise *instances* don't have an `.all` method. Only `Promise.all` exists. It  seems like you want something more like `Promise.all(userLogArray).then(() => validateInputClass(...)).then(response => { ...; console.log('done'); })`;?

Comment: Maybe, but I would prefer to do the all() after validateInputClass()

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me but you can do whatever you want of course. Main point is that promises have no `.all` method. So whatever you thought `somePromise.all()` would do, you have to do differently.

Comment: Also, `new Promise((user) => {console.log(user)});` makes no sense. Read a bit about promise constructor callbacks.

Comment: also, as you don't return anything in the `.map` callback, you'll end up with an array of `undefined` - so, you also need to read a bit about the Array map method

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually I need to return an array of Promises from the map, due to the .all() method requiring an array of promises to work through

Comment: I know what you "need", I was pointing out what your code will "get"

Comment: Looks like you are accustomed to using Bluebird, which does have this `all` method